# What ways do you use to protect copy righted images?

Tags: image, web

What ways do you use to protect copy righted images in your website?

Comment: What do you mean by protecting them? What are you trying to prevent/avoid?

Comment: Copyright is automatically applied in my country, so I don't *have to* do anything. I usually put a "copyright (c) xxx" at the bottom of the page, just because it makes me feel better.

Comment: What use are the images and what are the important parts? For example, if putting a date at the bottom right of each one is going to be problematic then that could be useful. Do you want to use steganography, and hide some encrypted data in the image?

Comment: Copyright gives you the legal backing to sue someone who uses your pictures in a way you don't permit.  There's no "protection" expressed or implied in copyright -- just support from participating governments to assert your rights.  What are you asking?

Comment: @S.Lott Make it as hard as possible to copy my images, without loosing quality (watermarks/low res)

Comment: @Itay Moav: Since that's impossible, what do you mean by "protection"?  If you allow download, then -- well -- you have to be sure they aren't published by someone else without your permission.  There are no "technical" means for doing this.  It's entirely a legal matter.  If you watermark, they aren't high-quality.  Since you have contradictory goals, please clarify what you're trying to do.  Also, please **update** the question with your clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Really the only way to protect images is to put huge watermarks on them, or only show them smaller than their original size. This is assuming you're displaying art or something else of that nature. All the tricks of disabling right click or using a css background or making a script output the image data only slow people down. If you can see something, you can save it. All it takes is a screenshot.

Comment: How does this "protect" them?

Comment: This protects them in the sense that if you have the original-resolution version, and the non-watermarked version, and you have never shared these with anyone, then these images become strong evidence of ownership, in the event that an infringer claims ownership.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you can whilst people have the ability to hit "alt-print screen".  You can prevent right clicking so they can't directly download the image and you can protect your folders so that you can't directly navigate to the image but that's about it really.

alt-print screen is your biggest permanent problem.

Comment: You can't prevent direct navigation to the pics - they still need to be available for an HTTP get, so to get the image that is all i have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Put them behind a protected area and only give access to people you trust. If it's of the public portion on the site, you can't protect them. You can just inform people that the images are copyrighted, but the users can grab them at will.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know any method that you works 100% however,
**don't upload high quality images**,it means that people can get but hesitate to use your images by trying these circumvented methods:

- no right-click script
- Shrink wrapping letting the thief download something other than original one.
- Watermarking
- Using Flash makes harder to get it